# How to play the video which is stored in directory cache in Google TV device

Tags: android, video, google-tv

I am downloading video and image files,and storing that files into the cache memory of the device.

i.e  like

```
    String RootDir = getCacheDir() + File.separator + "FirstData";
    RootFile = new File(RootDir);
    RootFile.mkdir();
```

But while using all those files fom the directory inside the cache the video file is not playing. It is showing "sorry this video cannot be played" alert.
and the log cat is coming like:

```
03-13 12:12:03.180: E/MediaPlayer(5093): error (1, -2147483648)
03-13 12:12:03.340: E/MediaPlayer(5093): Error (1,-2147483648)\
```

I have set the file name like .mp4 format and also I have set the

```
file.setReadable(true,false);
```

The same downloaded content if i place getCacheDir() location its working properly. But only the problem is if the file is inside the directory of getCacheDir()+Directory memory then it's showing the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mkdirs() instead of mkdir(),which will create the entire path.